Quartz.net doesnt work for WithIntervalInHours but works for WithIntervalInMinutes
I am trying to schedule a job using Quartz.net. The job triggers for WithIntervalInMinutes but not for WithIntervalInHours
 // Get the scheduler instance
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

        // Start the scheduler
        scheduler.Start();
        // Build the job detail
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ScheduledJob>().Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
          .StartNow()
          .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
           .WithIntervalInMinutes(10)
           .RepeatForever())
          .Build();

        // Schedule the job with the trigger
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

The scheduler is triggered a job for WithIntervalInMinutes. But i need to trigger WithIntervalInHours using below code
  ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(s =>
                    s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                        .OnEveryDay()
                        .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))
                )
                .Build();

